# How to include swc into a project in Flash Builder (Not merge into code, is include a swc)

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, intellij-idea, adobe

I was using IntelliJ for developing ActionScript project. Recently, I want to porting my project to Flash Builder. The main problem is I cannot find "include" option in linkage type.

Anyone has idea about this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

its not very intuitive but heres how you change it;

1. Flash Builder menu: project -> properties
2. Select 'Flex Build Path' in properties window and ensure 'Library Path' tab is open.
3. Click on arrow next to a listed SWC (or add a new one with 'Add SWC') to expand.
4. Double-click on 'link type' and change the value in the popup window that appears.

ps: IntelliJ is better than FB ;)

Comment: The problem is there is only two options in the expanded list, one is merge into code and other is "external....". I didn't find something like"include into codes".

Comment: merge = include, external = exclude. what other options would there be?

Comment: No, merge into codes means only include referenced classes or it would crash when create some objects by using getDefinitionByName(There is why somebody need to declare some classes at the start). This is because some classes are not included into the final swf. "Include into the codes" means whatever class you used or not are all linked into the final swf.

Comment: I wonder why Flash Builder don't include such an important feature. However, we can implement it with MXMLC which is not as handle as Flash Builder.

Comment: @Tinggo - you are mistaken; merge means include the classes, external means include references only.